# Универсальные отступы в галерее картинок

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать сетку фотографий 5х2, что соответствует замыслу дизайнера. Если все картинки присутствуют, то реализовать не составляет труда ровно и как надо, но если сетка рушится по той или иной причине (не влезает 5 картинок в линию, недостаточно картинок на линию из 5), то возникают сложности. Сложность что первая и последняя картинка в линии должна упираться во границу контейнера (.wrapper), таким образом не получается просто взять и использовать например псевдокласс :first-of-type и аналогичные чтобы просто убрать лишний отступ у крайнего элемента.

HTML:

```
<section class="portfolio">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="gallery">
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    margin-right: 140px;
    margin-left:  140px;
}

.portfolio .gallery{
    list-style-type: none; 
    height: 550px;
    text-align:center;   
}

.portfolio .gallery > li{
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: grey;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Обнуление отступа у каждого крайнего элемента*/
/* Ломается при недостаче элементов */
.portfolio .gallery li:nth-of-type(5n)
{ margin-right: 0; }
```

Как быть?

Comment: для начала я бы спросил у дизайнера, как он планировал отображать такие случаи. не задача верстальщика фантазировать.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Нет возможности, макет no-name. Да и сомневаюсь, что дизайнер задумывался над такими моментами.

Comment: @YesMan А можете сделать ваш код запускаемым?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю выровнять строки картинок по ширине, включая последнюю строку.

```
.portfolio .gallery {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
}
```

И воспользоваться опытом Бутстрапа: всем картинкам дать поля с обеих сторон, а списку — такого же размера отрицательные поля. Будет выглядеть, будто у крайних картинок нет отступа, а псевдоклассы для этого не понадобятся.

```
.portfolio .gallery {
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-right: -50px;
}
.portfolio .gallery > li {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Получится, например, так: http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/EZjOXB

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-right: 140px;
  margin-left:  140px;
}

.portfolio .gallery {
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-right: -50px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
}

.portfolio .gallery > li {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="gallery">
      <li> </li>
      <li> </li>
      <li> </li>
      <li> </li>
      <li> </li>
      <li> </li>
      <li> </li>
      <li> </li>
      <li> </li>
      <li> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на собственный вопрос.

Как вариант, можно оставить отступы справа, но сместить влево на такую же длину сам контейнер с картинками.

```
.portfolio .gallery{
    list-style-type: none; 
    height: 550px;
    text-align:center; 

    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
}
```

От этого возникают, правда, другие проблемы, но это уже другая история.

Если есть мысли как сделать лучше, пишите.